# Not able to start spring boot project

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I've tried to start a spring boot project. It doesn't start. Here are my build.gradle config changes and application local yml file.

```
imports {
    mavenBom "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:Greenwich.SR3"
    mavenBom "io.pivotal.spring.cloud:spring-cloud-services-dependencies:2.1.2.RELEASE"
    mavenBom "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-contract-dependencies:2.1.1.RELEASE" 
    
}
```

I made a bean definition overriding property as well

```
spring:
   main:
       allow-bean-definition-overriding: true
```

However, it is not starting. Here is the main exception

```
{"@timestamp":"2020-09-09T14:58:53.489-04:00","@version":"1","message":"\r\n\r\n***************************\r\nAPPLICATION FAILED TO START\r\n***************************\r\n\r\nDescription:\r\n\r\n

The bean 'dataSource', defined in BeanDefinition defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfig
ure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class], could not be registered. A bean with that name has already been defi
ned in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfig
uration$Hikari.class] 
and overriding is disabled.\r\n\r\nAction:\r\n\r\nConsider renaming one of the beans 
or enabling overriding
 by setting spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true\r\n","logger_name":"org.springframework.boot.diagnostics.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter","thread_name":"main","level":"ERROR","level_value":40000}
```

What else am I missing?

Comment: Check this thread, maybe it will help to track down the underlaying issue
https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-config/issues/1142

Comment: Can you post your DataSourceConfiguration class?